# Is there a way to do cleanup before application exits when clicking stop casting in chrome extention?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I want to do cleanup both in the receiver and on the sender application when the user is stop casting by using the stop casting in chrome extension.

I can see in the receiver documentation that there are an event `cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.EventType.SHUTDOWN` (Fired when the system is terminated.) but there are no corresponding onShutdown event handler like onReady. Is there a way to be notified when a application terminated and be able to do some cleanup before it ends(tracking that a  movie not longer is playing)

The sender application also need to get a shutdown event so it can do cleaning operation?

Comment: Right now there's no option to clean up when stop casting command is issued.  We're working on that and will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly you want to clean up, but asuming you want to clean up after all clients disconnected, this might help:

```
// handler for 'senderdisconnected' event
    castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
      console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
      if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
        console.log('no more senders, shutting down.');
        window.close();
      }
    };
```